# Is there another way to post automatically to my own Facebook page than using a long-lived page access token hardcoded into my code?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am an admin of a Facebook page where I could post automatically an URL and a message every morning via a Python script for several months.

So far I used Facebook Graph API via a daily-ran Python script for this purpose with a never-expiring Page Access Token having **manage_pages** and **publish_pages** permissions. To obtain such an access token I followed a description similar to [this](https://adamboother.com/blog/automatically-posting-to-a-facebook-page-using-the-facebook-sdk-v5-for-php-facebook-api/). According to its steps I had to create an app on https://developers.facebook.com/apps. Finally I succeeded.

My Python code (including the never-expiring page access token) to post automatically on my Facebook page looked similar to this:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse

def fb_auto_post():

    page_id = 'page_id_of_my_page'
    page_access_token = 'never-expiring_page_access_token_of_my_page'
    message = 'my_message' #(string) automatically generated by a previous function based on analyzing some daily data
    link = 'my_link'
    
    to_graph_API = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + page_id + '/feed?message=' + urllib.parse.quote(message) + '&link=' + link + '&method=POST&access_token=' + page_access_token
    
    urllib.request.urlopen(to_graph_API)
    
fb_auto_post()
```

This code worked fine for several months but now Facebook is performing an app review where my app failed and didn’t get approval for **manage_pages** and **publish_pages** permissions which both are required to continue posting automatically on my page. As a result I cannot use the above code anymore since my page access token has no permission to post to my page.

Now I am stuck and have two questions:

## 1:

I understand that [Facebook will no longer let apps automatically post to their users’ timelines or pages](http://www.businessinsider.com/facebook-no-longer-lets-apps-automatically-post-to-your-profile-2018-4) and that's why my app did not get the required permissions. But is there an exception if the only page I want to post to automatically is my own? For example I found this quote in a [manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens):

> "Your app might not need to request these permissions because people
> posting are already set up with a role in your app's dashboard. If
> this is the case you do not need to submit your app for review. See
> the Roles tab in App Dashboard."

Since I am the admin of the app and also the admin of the only page I want to post to I think the quote fits to my case but I couldn't figure out how can I implement the exception described in it.

## 2:

The only reason I have created an app is to generate a long-lived page access token which I can insert into my Python code. Is there a way to bypass using a Facebook App? For example, is it possible to somehow automatically generate a short-lived page access token every morning via the Graph API? (As I’ve experienced, short-lived page access tokens still have the mage_pages and publish_pages permissions.)

Sorry for the very long problem description and thank you for your answers!

Comment: 1) That exception isn’t valid any more. 2) No. And short-lived vs long-lived has nothing whatsoever to do with this in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe Well, this week I have generated a short-lived (valid for about 30-60 minutes) page access token which had both manage_pages and publish_pages permissions again. I did it manually via the Graph API Explorer using a short-lived user access token related not to my app but my personal profile. Maybe that's what counted and not the token being short-lived, so I was wondering whether I could automate this process somehow instead of using the same never-expiring page access token every day.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a second application, not auditing, temporary use, waiting for the first application to be successfully audited, switching to a new permanent access_token

Comment: This solution circumvents the problem. It does not resolve it.